# Check if MongoDB collection exists in loopback v3. If not create with custom properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback

Is there anyway in nodeJS to check if a mongoDB collection exists, using Loopback v3, and if not to create with custom properties ?

For example, we created a custom collection in MongoDB using CLI as follows:

```
use myDatabase
db.createCollection("UserName", { collation: { locale: 'en_US', strength: 2 } } )
db.UserName.createIndex({email: 1})
```

In my model JSON file I have:

```
{
  "name": "UserName",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "strictObjectIDCoercion": true,
    "mongodb": {
      "collection": "UserName"
    }   
  }
```

In our API code, we need to reference this collection, but I wanted to check if Collection exists first and if not to create as above i.e.

```
if (typeof app.models.UserName === 'undefined' {
   // create collection with custom properties as above
}
```